# GUI Won't load after changing size

Tags: java, user-interface, layout

In a bit of a panic. Been working on a project for the past two months. I changed a few of the box sizes a couple of days ago and saved it. Reloaded it this morning and the window size has gone stupidly small and I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: javax.swing.JButton[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.5,border=javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthBorder@ce623f,flags=288,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,defaultIcon=,disabledIcon=,disabledSelectedIcon=,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],paintBorder=true,paintFocus=true,pressedIcon=,rolloverEnabled=true,rolloverIcon=,rolloverSelectedIcon=,selectedIcon=,text=Search,defaultCapable=true] is not attached to a horizontal group
```

Any ideas??!?!?!?!

Comment: That's easy to solve.  Check out the last known working copy from your version control, and see what you changed.

Comment: Last copy was done around a week ago. Although I haven't made massive changes, it's a pain in the ass to go back. All did to the previous program was select all text boxes, right click - set to same size?

Comment: Well there's definitely a lesson for you there.  (What would you have done if your hard disc had died unexpectedly?)

Comment: It's on dropbox ;) But yes, daily backups will now be done!

Comment: Hicks - I should point out that if you are using a decent VC system, and you are using it properly (checking in frequently), it is not a pain to review your history or check out an old version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says it all. You have a certain component (a `JButton`) which you have added to a vertical group but forgot to add it to a horizontal group as well in your `GroupLayout`. See the [How to use `GroupLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html) part of the `LayoutManager` tutorial and the corresponding sample code

```
layout.setHorizontalGroup(
   layout.createSequentialGroup()
      .addComponent(c1)
      .addComponent(c2)
      .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
           .addComponent(c3)
           .addComponent(c4))
);
layout.setVerticalGroup(
   layout.createSequentialGroup()
      .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
           .addComponent(c1)
           .addComponent(c2)
           .addComponent(c3))
      .addComponent(c4)
);
```

If you would remove the `addComponent(c3)` part from the first line you would receive a similar exception.

Of course, without seeing your code I cannot pinpoint where exactly in your project you messed up, but a decent VCS-based diff tool to compare between those 2 versions should reveal this pretty quickly

Comment: That's all well - but every time I go to change the size of text field for example, it allows me to drag it to the width I want - but then goes back to its original size?

Comment: What is the 'it' to which you are referring ? Are you talking about a graphical UI builder/editor like Netbeans have ? In that case I cannot help you as I hand-code all my UI's

Comment: Yes - Netbeans. I'm guessing hand-coded GUI are better but in return, much harder / longer.